# DHCP -> scope 1 WiFi , scope 2 others

Tags: dhcp, wifi

I work on 2003 server, and I have a DHCP with 1 scope 10.2.1.0/8

I would like to create a second scope 10.2.2.0/8 for attribute this scope for WiFi clients and the first scope for LAN clients (RJ45)

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your scopes, just ensure that your WIFI scope is only associated with your WIFI adapter, and your LAN scope is connected only to your LAN adapter.

Your netmasks are incorrect - judging by your network IDs I would guess you want /24 not /8.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a router if you want to have two separate subnets (or an extra interface on you'r existing router/firewall). You'll also need to enable DHCP relay on that new interface and point it to your existing DHCP server.

BTW: Your subnet masks are way off, unless your are using inverted masks? Are the subnet 255.255.255.0 (/24)?